# Waiting for a synchronous function with internal callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, shutdown

I have a few synchronous functions, some of which are not my own code.
These functions accept and execute callback functions upon completion.

I need to wait until these callbacks are finished and exit the application after that.
How can I enforce this?

```
const serverGracefulShutdown = () => {

  logger.info('Signal received: Gracefully killing application');

  httpServer.close(() => {
    logger.info('Apollo server closed');
  });

  redis.quit(() => {
    logger.info('Redis client closed');
  });

  stopKafkaConsumer(() => {
    logger.info('Kafka consumer closed');
  });

  logger.info('Application closed');
  process.exit(0);
};

process.on('SIGINT', serverGracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', serverGracefulShutdown);
```

In the code above I want to ensure graceful shutdown of application.

All the running stuff is stopped and then I can call *process.exit(0)*.

Comment: Promsify everything and use `Promise.all()`.  Otherwise, you have to implement some sort of counter and then in every callback, you decrement the counter and check to see if the counter has gotten to zero indicating that all the callbacks are now done.

Comment: FOr some reason I thought I can only make Promise out of async functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to play with promises:

```js
const serverGracefulShutdown = () => {

  logger.info('Signal received: Gracefully killing application');

  const promises = [

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => httpServer.close(() => {
      // do you get an optional error param inside this callback?
      // if yes, then "if (error) reject(error) else resolve()"
      // (or any other way to mark this operation as failed)
      logger.info('Apollo server closed');
      resolve();
    })),

    new Promise((resolve /* + reject? */) => redis.close(() => {
      logger.info('Redis client closed');
      resolve();
    })),

    new Promise((resolve /* + reject? */) => stopKafkaConsumer(() => {
      logger.info('Kafka consumer closed');
      resolve();
    }))

  ];

  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    logger.info('Application closed');
    process.exit(0);
  }).catch((error) => {
    // what's your plan if at least one failed?
  });

};

process.on('SIGINT', serverGracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', serverGracefulShutdown);
```

Comment: This is what confuses me a little. I have nothing to "resolve" after the code runs. I just need to know when that inner callback is finished, so I know that HTTP server is down and I can close Redis and Kafka, after which I can quit Node.

Comment: @MichalFašánek Well, "after which I can quit Node" sounds like a "resolve" to me :) "Once all connections have been closed, stop the server": there's something asynchronous here, you need to wait for some things to happen before doing some other things, which is basically the job of promises. You can't just wait for something in a synchronous manner in Node.js anyway, so it's either callbacks (like the other answer proposes) or (callbacks disguised into) promises :)

Comment: After some trouble, I found out this: If I pass no callback into those exit functions, they return a Promise. That is a huge win for me. Now my code is simple and works. But nobody bothered to put this into documentation. After consulting my coworker, this seems to be a common implementation in Node. But it really frustrated me, I should be able to see this without knowing the house rules of the community. Thank you for your knowledge though.

Comment: @MichalFašánek Oh, that's great, feel free to answer your own question then :) I guess you're still making use of Promise#all though, aren't you? Building that array of promises should just look less clumsy now, possibly even inlined with the call to Promise#all directly if those are now one-liners :)

Comment: I used the Promise#all, thus I will accept this answer. My final logic is: Close the HTTP server(might need Redis and Kafka) -> then close Redis and Kafka in parallel -> then kill the application.

Possibly for everyone: check the return type of operations.